# Select Number of Values in Database Column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a mySQL table called `palettes`, and I want to return the number of links in the table.  Basically, I want to return the number of values in the `link` column.  (In this case, `6`).

I tried using this code, but it didn't work.  I'm a front-end dev, with NO knowledge of php or anything..

```
include "mysql.php";
$select_rows = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(link) FROM palettes");
$rows = mysqli_fetch_array($select_rows);
$total = $rows[0];
echo $total;
```

The above code should or echoed `6`, right?  Selecting from column `link`

This is what my table looks like:

[image]

Comment: Are the empty values `NULL` or the empty string? `COUNT` ignores `NULL`, but zero-length strings are counted.

Comment: If every link is a http site, I would use the WHERE clause with LIKE 'http%' and change your query to count id's that fit: $select_rows = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($cxn, "SELECT id FROM palettes WHERE link LIKE 'http%'"));

Comment: Empty values are `NULL`.  It's an optional field in a form.  Maybe an if statement?  If column LINK has values, count them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the WHERE clause with LIKE 'http%' and change your query to count id's that fit:

First, I'll assume your file 'mysql.php' has a connection to the database somewhere in the file like this:

```
<?php
if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {session_start();}

$hostname = 'localhost';
$dbname   = 'myDatabaseName';
$username = 'admin';
$password = 'myPassword';

$cxn = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname) or DIE('Connection to host is failed, perhaps the service is down!');

?>//End connect.php
```

Now you can try this:

```
include 'mysql.php';
$select_rows = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($cxn, "SELECT id FROM palettes WHERE link LIKE 'http%'"));

echo $select_rows; //Should = 6
```

Comment: It can be https, too.  So would you do `SELECT id FROM palettes WHERE link LIKE 'http%' || LIKE 'https%'`

Comment: No need to account for an "or": % is a wildcard for the MySQL LIKE statement

Comment: Thanks man!  Got it to work.  Just had to change `id` to `count(id)`

Answer (score 0):

I would say place NULL in case you don't have the link available:

You can do it by making the Link column to allow NULL as default. You can make use of the COUNT(Link) in that case. This is recommended.

If you have to have empty string instead of NULLs.

```
select sum(if(Link != "",1,0)) counting from palettes;
```

Or if you can make sure all the links start with http/https

```
select sum(if(Link like "http%",1,0)) counting from palettes;
```

Comment: `include "mysql.php";$select_rows = $mysqli->query("SELECT link FROM palettes WHERE link IS NOT NULL");$rows = mysqli_fetch_array($select_rows);$total = $rows[0];echo $total;` seems to return all the values, but how would I get the number of values, not actual value?

Comment: As you said the values are not NULL values they are empty string right? your NOT NULL condition fails every time.

Comment: The empty are `NULL`, sorry :P

Comment: well, are you sure? that doesn't seem like. If they would have NULL, you would have directly work with COUNT. Moreover NULL will be visible instead of empty spaces